# Set theory - x NOT belogs to a symmetric difference of 3 sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I don't think I really get the concept of what it means to NOT belong to a symmetric difference on 3 sets.

**I have this question:**
If $x \notin A \bigtriangleup B \bigtriangleup C$ Then $x \notin A \bigtriangleup B$

As I understand, this is **not true**. But I would like to get a detailed explanation of why.
Basically, what does it mean to NOT TO be in $A \bigtriangleup B \bigtriangleup C$

Comment: See [Symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference): the diagrams.

Answer (score 1):

One first proves that symmetric difference is associative, i.e., that $$(A\triangle B)\triangle C=A\triangle(B\triangle C)\,$$ so that one can write $A\triangle B\triangle C$ without any danger of ambiguity. Now let $D=A\triangle B$; then

$$A\triangle B\triangle C=D\triangle C=(D\setminus C)\cup(C\setminus D)\,.$$

This means that $x\in A\triangle B\triangle C$ if and only if $x\in D\setminus C$ **or** $x\in C\setminus D$. In other words, $x\in A\triangle B\triangle C$ if and only if $x\in(A\triangle B)\setminus C$ **or** $x\in C\setminus(A\triangle B)$. It’s perfectly true that if $x\in C\setminus(A\triangle B)$, then $x\notin A\triangle B$, but that’s not the only way that $x$ can get into $A\triangle B\triangle C$: everything in $A\triangle B$ that isn’t in $C$ is also in $A\triangle B\triangle C$.

As a very simple example, let $A=\{0\}$, $B=\{1\}$, and $C=\{2\}$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
A\triangle B\triangle C&=\big(\{0\}\triangle\{1\}\big)\triangle\{2\}\\
&=\{0,1\}\triangle\{2\}\\
&=\{0,1,2\}\,,
\end{align*}$$

and in this case $A\triangle B\triangle C$ actually contains **every** member of $A\triangle B$.

You should try to prove that $A\triangle B\triangle C$ is the set of all things that belong to an odd number of the sets $A,B$, and $C, i.e., the things that belong to exactly one of these sets or to all three. More generally, the symmetric difference of any finite family of sets consists of those things that are elements of an odd number of the sets in the family.

Comment: Thank you so much! :D

Comment: You’re welcome!